# Vim suspend/resume startup/shutdown hooks

Tags: vim

Is it possible to execute a shell command when I suspend and resume vim? I guess that I can do something once `<C-z>` is pressed, so this can be considered us a suspend hook. But what about resume (with `fg`)? And also is it possible to do some work on vim startup and shutdown?

Maybe it's possible to establish handlers for vim's `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm trying to execute arbitrary shell command when vim quits/starts/suspends/resumes. What shell command exactly? Well, it's a super long story... but the problem isn't in what I'm trying to do using this shell command, the problem is "is it possible, to establish those hooks? and if yes, how?"

Comment: `:help autocommand-events`

Comment: @romainl Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for! I'm gonna try them out, can you write an answer so that I could mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [help](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) on `autocommand-events` (suggested by @romainl) says, you can use `VimEnter` and `VimLeave` to execute a command when Vim launches or shuts down:

```
autocmd VimEnter * call EnterFunc()
autocmd VimLeave * call LeaveFunc()
```

The above code will execute a function `EnterFunc` when launching Vim, and `LeaveFunc` when exiting Vim.

To execute a function when vim is suspended or resumed, you can use `VimSuspend` or `VimResume`:

```
autocmd VimSuspend * call SuspendFunc()
autocmd VimResume * call ResumeFunc()
```

However, you should know that `VimSuspend` and `VimResume` are available only from Vim 8.2. If you're using Ubuntu you can add this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
```

and then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

to update vim to a version that supports `VimSuspend` and `VimResume`.
This is outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290827)